# Найти в массиве из объектов, то что есть в другом массиве

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив например:

```
let arrName = ['Alex','Petr','Lena','Jon'];
```

И массив из объектов:

```js
 let obj = [{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Dima',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Alex',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Irina',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Oleg',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Lena',age:30}
}]
```

Вопрос как мне найти совпадения из массива arrName в obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arrName = ['Alex','Petr','Lena','Jon'];
let obj = [{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Dima',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Alex',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Irina',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Oleg',age:30}
},{
       key: 1,
       map: 0,
       list: {name: 'Lena',age:30}
}]

const result = obj.filter(e => arrName.includes(e.list.name));
console.log(result);
```

**Подробнее**
[`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) - метод, который сообщает есть ли элемент в массиве
[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - метод, который фильтрует массив по определенному условию